# Hadoop error while using this command hadoop fs -mkdir /in

Tags: windows, hadoop, hadoop2

[image: Commandline screenshot]

Hadoop command: `hadoop fs -mkdir /in` tried in folder `C:\hwork` but it did not work properly. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: do you manage to make any hadoop fs command work ? it seems like your hadoop install might not work

Comment: i am new user in hadoop. so i can't undertsand what issue is goin on. i work hadoop setup in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhxWig96dME

Comment: By the way, screen shots of error messages are a lot less useful than the actual text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to visit the namenode UI before doing any filesystem operations to verify your HDFS cluster is actually working. The error message you have given indicates that it is not.

The namenode UI is typically available on `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp`.

You can also verify that HDFS is working properly by running the following command:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

If "Safe Mode is ON", then things are not running properly. You should also have a non-zero configured capacity and at least one datanode which is available.

A healthy pseudo-distributed HDFS environment should give a report that looks something like this:

```
Configured Capacity: 41746268160 (38.88 GB)
Present Capacity: 34658451456 (32.28 GB)
DFS Remaining: 34655678464 (32.28 GB)
DFS Used: 2772992 (2.64 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Live datanodes:
Name: 192.168.10.129:50010 (datanode)
Hostname: datanode
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 41746268160 (38.88 GB)
DFS Used: 2772992 (2.64 MB)
Non DFS Used: 7087816704 (6.60 GB)
DFS Remaining: 34655678464 (32.28 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
DFS Remaining%: 83.02%
Last contact: Thu May 07 16:51:50 UTC 2015
```